# Applying a convex function to a weak solution yields a weak subsolution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

PDE Evans, 2nd edition: Chapter 6, Exercise 11

> Assume $u \in H^1(U)$ is a bounded weak solution of $$-\sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij}u_{x_i})_{x_j} = 0 \quad \text{in }U.$$ Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex and smooth, and set $w=\phi(u)$. Show $w$ is a weak subsolution; that is, $B[w,v] \le 0$ for all $v \in H_0^1(u)$, $v \ge 0$.

Attempted proof:

Given $w=\phi(u)$, we find the derivative $w_{x_i}=\phi'(u) u_{x_i}$. Also, since $\phi$ is convex, $\phi''(u) \ge 0$. We use integration by parts to deduce that 
\begin{align*}
B[w,v]&=\int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij} w_{x_i} v_{x_j} \, dx \\
&= \int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij} \phi'(u) u_{x_i} v_{x_j} \, dx \\
&= -\int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij} \phi'(u) u_{x_i})_{x_j} v \, dx \\
&= -\int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij} u_{x_i} [\phi'(u)]_{x_j} v  + \sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij} u_{x_i})_{x_j} \phi'(u) v \, dx \\
&= -\int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij} \phi''(u) u_{x_i} u_{x_j} v \, dx  \\
&= -\int_U \phi''(u) v \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij} u_{x_i} u_{x_j} \, dx \\ 
&\le 0
\end{align*}
for all $v \in H_0^1(U)$, $v \ge 0$.

**Question:** I am confident that I started correctly. However, my very last inequality is not clear. I tried to expand my penultimate step using a product-to-sum inequality (i.e. Minkowski's inequality), but then again I have a minus sign and I don't know if my terms are non-negative.

Comment: Cookie, could you explain me the 5th equality? How did you eliminate the second term?

Comment: @Pedro Since $u$ solves the PDE $-\sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij}u_{x_i})_{x_j} = 0$, we are able to eliminate the second term: $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij}u_{x_i})_{x_j} \phi'(u) v= 0\phi'(u) v$$

Comment: Cookie, For this, are you assuming $\phi'(u)v\in C_c^\infty(U)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standing assumption in exercises  in that chapter is that the coefficients $a^{ij}$ satisfy an ellipticity condition. In particular, the matrix $A=(a^{ij})$ is positive definite, which implies
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij} u_{x_i} u_{x_j} = \nabla u^T A\nabla u\ge 0$$
Since also $v\ge 0$ and $\phi''\ge 0$, the conclusion
$$-\int_U \phi''(u) v \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij} u_{x_i} u_{x_j} \, dx \le 0$$ follows.